# Connecting with a specific interface in Linux

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I have connected two ethernet cards in the CPU. I have then connected one card to internet another one card to the modem. Its working fine. from modem i have connected to another linux pc.when i m ping the another pc ip address from my machine its not pinging.how to configure it

Comment: DON'T SHOUT ! Downvoted for uppercase. I won't even edit.

Comment: I removed the all-caps and made some edits to the question. From the body I assumed the "aspecific" in the title was really meant to be "a specific". Please change it in case you really meant "aspecific" (=non specific). Also, I assumed you wanted to do this in C, as you used the C tag. Finally, you may want to really improve your question, for instance by telling us what you already tried. As it stands the question is of very low quality.

Comment: Based on your question history, you seem to be having some problems with using SO. Try reading the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how and what to ask. In general, if you don't show any effort be prepared to answer [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3):

If you have two interfaces, you have two IP addresses.

Bind your socket to the IP address/port you want to use.

You can read [this socket tutorial](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm) for operations step by step on Linux.

Comment: thank u aubin !!!Before going to the coding section what are the configuration settings should be made in the two systems

Comment: I have connected two ethernet cards in the CPU. I have then connected one card to internet another one card  to the modem. Its working fine. from modem i have connected to another linux pc.when i m ping the another pc ip address from my machine its not pinging.how to configure it.

Comment: what are the basic settings i should make in both the pc's